# C++ map allocator stores items in a vector?

Tags: c++, iterator, allocator

Here is the problem I would like to solve: in C++, iterators for map, multimap, etc are missing two desirable features: (1) they can't be checked at run-time for validity, and (2) there is no operator< defined on them, which means that they can't be used as keys in another associative container.  (I don't care whether the operator< has any relationship to key ordering; I just want there to be some < available at least for iterators to the same map.)

Here is a possible solution to this problem: convince map, multimap, etc to store their key/data pairs in a vector, and then have the iterators be a small struct that contain a pointer to the vector itself and a subscript index.  Then two iterators, at least for the same container, could be compared (by comparing their subscript indices), and it would be possible to test at run time whether an iterator is valid.

Is this solution achievable in standard C++?  In particular, could I define the 'Allocator' for the map class to actually put the items in a vector, and then define the Allocator::pointer type to be the small struct described in the last paragraph?  How is the iterator for a map related to the Allocator::pointer type?  Does the Allocator::pointer have to be an actual pointer, or can it be anything that supports a dereference operation?

---

UPDATE 2013-06-11: I'm not understanding the responses.  If the (key,data) pairs are stored in a vector, then it is O(1) to obtain the items given the subscript, only slightly worse than if you had a direct pointer, so there is no change in the asymptotics.  Why does a responder say map iterators are "not kept around"?  The standard says that iterators remain valid as long as the item to which they refer is not deleted.  As for the 'real problem': say I use a multimap for a symbol table (variable name->storage location; it is a multimap rather than map because the variables names in an inner scope may shadow variables with the same name), and say now I need a second data structure keyed by variables.  The apparently easiest solution is to use as key for the second map an iterator to the specific instance of the variable's name in the first map, which would work if only iterators had an operator<.

Comment: If you do this, you lose the ability to insert and remove elements in O(log N) time, which is required for `std::map` and friends.

Comment: You can use a custom comparison function for your map.

Comment: What is the *real* problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 4):

I think not.

If you were somehow able to "convince" `map` to store its pairs in a vector, you would fundamentally change certain (at least two) guarantees on the `map`:

1. `insert`, `erase` and `find` would no longer be logarithmic in complexity.
2. `insert`  would no longer be able to guarantee the validity of unaffected iterators, as the underlying `vector` would sometimes need to be reallocated.

Taking a step back though, two things suggest to me that you are trying to "solve" the wrong problem.

First, it is unusual to need to have a vector of iterators.

Second, it is unusual to need to check an iterator for validity, as iterators are not generally kept around.

I wonder what the *real* problem is that you are trying to solve?